# Grabbing first child <span> from the parent element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

What jQuery function would I use to grab the closest to the top of a `div <span>` and also the very last in the list as well?

Answer (score 7):

The HTML

```
<div id="spans">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

the jQuery:

```
$('#spans span:first,#spans span:last');
```

Your question requires more explanation but this is a punt at what your looking for.

Comment: Note you can also use `:last`

Comment: `jQuery('div span:first, div span:last')` might more closely match the question.